# Puppeteer - page.$

Tags: javascript, puppeteer

I am launching a webpage in puppeteer using page.goto(url). clicking to a second page and then am trying to look for a buy now button on that second page.
Currently I am using
let buynowquery = page.$('#buy-now-button');

However, each time I am getting a 'pending' promise return i.e. I can't do anything useful with that information. I am guessing the page cannot be scanned in time

What can I do to resolve this?
Thanks

Comment: Please, read [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/puppeteer/get-started#usage) as the first part of basic research before asking a question on Stack Overflow. See the [tour] and [ask], whose first section is titled "Search, and research...".

Answer (score 1):

I think you miss the `await`:

```js
let buynowquery = await page.$('#buy-now-button');
```

If you want to make sure the element is visible, because the page might need some time to load, you can use [`waitForSelector`](https://pptr.dev/#?product=Puppeteer&version=v8.0.0&show=api-pagewaitforselectorselector-options):

```js
let buynowquery = await page.waitForSelector('#buy-now-button');
```

In the examples above `buynowquery` will resolve to an [`ElementHandle`](https://pptr.dev/#?product=Puppeteer&version=v8.0.0&show=api-class-elementhandle), so you can trigger actions like a `click` on the element:

```js
await buynowquery.click();
```